# multi-tenancy Vue and nginx (1 Vue app for multi customer with multi subDomain)

Tags: vue.js, nginx

I have 3 url

http://my.com/shop/customerA to customer A

http://my.com/shop/customerB to customer B

http://my.com/shop/customerC to customer C

There is only one vue app (Customer ID obtained from http header)

The nginx configuration file is as follows

No problem with static files
But .js will have problems

But how to set vue VUE_APP_publicPath? (It should not be able to switch dynamically)

Or how should nginx add settings?

Thank you for your assistance, I have been researching for a long time

```
server {
listen 8121;
root /usr/share/nginx/my.com/shop;
To
location / {
add_header X-uri "$uri";
try_files $uri $uri/ @router;
index index.html index.htm;
}

location @router {
rewrite ^.*$ /index.html last;
}
}

server {
    server_name my.com;
listen 80;

    location /shop {
#add_header X-uri "$uri $host $http_host$request_uri";
rewrite "^/shop/(.*?)/(.*)$" /$2 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8121/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply serve your Vue app from http://my.com/shop and make the top route in VueRouter to use a parameter - this parameter will be `customerA` or `customerB` or `customerC`

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with multi-tenancy lately in my projects but using vue with laravel for the SSR.

But if i was using only Vue, i probably do this.

In nginx, point to your main app only and remove the "location /shop" section.

You will be able to archive what you want by using the customer as parameter in vue-router.

Lets say that you have a path pages/.
Inside you will have a layout.vue
It will be your container.
You should add your logic to load the customer api here IMHO.

pages/layout.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="db-wrapper" class="toggled">
    
    <SideBar />

    <div id="page-content">
      <div class="header">

        <NavTop />

      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid p-4">
        <transition name="slide-in" mode="out-in">
          <router-view />
        </transition>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavTop from "@/components/navigations/NavTop";
import SideBar from "@/components/navigations/SideBar";

export default {
 components: {
    NavTop,
    SideBar,
 },
 mounted() {
   this.loadClient();
 },
 methods: {
    loadClient() {
    // get the customer http header.  
    // you will be able to get your customer as parameter
    //
    // let customer = this.$route.params.customer
    //
    // call your apis
    }  
 }
};
</script>
```

Now we need to deal with the router.

We will make pages/layout.vue be the router component that will wrap its pages.

You can try to make the url where the page will be in last.
my.com/customer/shop

If you don't you can revert the usage of the router.

router/index.js

```
  ...

  Vue.use(VueRouter);

  const routes = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "login",
    component: Login,
  },
  {
    path: ":customer",
    name: "layout",
    component: Layout,

    children: [
      {
        path: "shop",
        name: "shop",
        page_title: "Welcome to our shop",
        component: Shop,
      },
      {
        path: "checkout",
        name: "checkout",
        page_title: "Checkout",
        component: Checkout,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});
```